# Le « face shield for medical worker » : quel terme est le plus employé, quel terme chosir ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot, terminologie, santé-et-médecine

J'ai vu le terme « face shields for medical workers ». Le [GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2072056) privilégie « écran facial » en contexte industriel (soudure, électricité) mais l'image montre un élément couvrant la tête (comme une partie de casque); on [trouve](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18935972) aussi *masque de protection, masque protecteur*. Dans le domaine du sport on recense aussi [*pare-visage*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8887871). [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=FACE%20SHIELD&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) donne une panoplie de termes dont *visière-écran, écran protecteur* etc. Dans un article je lis « masque en plastique transparent et qui couvre l'intégralité du visage » ; c'est long longtemps quoique clair.

Quel terme est le plus employé et quel terme convient davantage au contexte des [travailleurs de la santé](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18056091) pour l'objet de plastique qui n'a pas d'élément couvrant la tête et s'intègre le mieux au lexique préexistant ; et pourquoi ?

Comment: « Visière de protection » est ce que j'entends le plus en ce moment.

Answer (score 2):

Personnellement j'ai toujours dit, et toujours entendu "visière" ou "visière de protection". Et cela quelque soit le domaine.

Après, je ne pourrais vous expliquer le pourquoi du comment est ce qu'on utilise ce mot en question.

Comment: En regardant les autres termes, en trouve-t-on un meilleur que celui-ci ; c'est en Amérique du Nord ou en Europe qu'on l'a dit/entendu ?

Comment: @Restezchezvous J'habite et je suis né en France, c'est donc en France (région parisienne) que je l'entends/le dit

Comment: @Restezchezvous D'ailleurs je n'ai jamais entendu aucun de vos exemple cité dans votre question